# PIC18F4550 : How to convert 16 bits integer to two 8 bits chars in C?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c, microchip, pic16f

I'm blocked because of an issue that is causing a lot of time loss. I've created a function to get the LSB and another one to get the MSB.

```
char get_LSB (int n){
    
    unsigned char lsb = (unsigned)n & 0xFF; // mask the lower 8 bits
   return lsb;
}

char get_MSB (int n){  
    unsigned char msb = ((unsigned)n >> 8 );// shift the higher 8 bits
   return msb;
}
```

It doesn't work as when I call the function get_LSB or get_MSB I get a result different from what I expected. Let's check the following example:

```
void main() {
              TRSISC = 0x00;
              PORTC = get_LSB(100);// function should return 100 but returns 68
              Delay_ms(5000);
              PORTC = get_MSB(360); // should return 1 but returns 0
}
```

Comment: The function are OK (except that I would suggest to change the parameter type to unsigned). You have some problem with testing. `get_MSB(360)` should be returning `0x68` - probably the result that you believe it is returning for `get_LSB(100)`. Please tell us how do you read out the results.

Comment: Why should get_MSB(360) return 0x68? It should return 0x01.

Comment: be careful, the return value is a char, which is different from a signed char and from an unsigned char, this is unspecified. To be clearer i suggest to use unsigned char or even better uint8_t if your compiler has it. As commented however it seems a base 16 misunderstanding

Comment: @jusaca You are right, 0x68 is the LSB, not MSB. Sounds like the program presented is different from the one that is flashed and run. Or there is a misinterpretation of the results.

Comment: @EugeneSh.I will try with an unsigned int as parameter for the function. For the check, I use the debugger of MIKROC and I check the content of PORTC and I see that PORTC = 68.

Comment: If you have a debugger, then assign the results to variables and check them. I am not sure how reliable is it in displaying ***output*** ports. Can't you directly measure the port values? Also make one test at a time to not get interference between the two.

Comment: @jusaca thanks for your reply. But where do you see that we should get 0x68 from get_MSB(360) ?

Comment: Assign your return values to do different variables and declare them to be static and volatile. 0x68 is the LSB of (dec) 100. This may be your debugger screwing up or the compiler changing the sequence and the optimizer eliminating or re-ordering statements. Also use clean type casts. You have unsigned ints on the right and unsigned chars on the left. The input to your functions should be unsigned in the first place. What do you expect for get_LSB(-27) ?

Comment: @hilmar 100 = 0x64 not 0x68

Comment: Oops, I meant it's the LSB of dec 360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these:

```
unsigned char get_LSB (int n)
{    
    unsigned char lsb = (unsigned char) (n & 0xFF); // mask the lower 8 bits
    return lsb;
}

unsigned char get_MSB (int n)
{  
    unsigned char msb = (unsigned char) (n >> 8);// shift the higher 8 bits
    return msb;
}
```

Comment: This really should not change any behavior

Comment: Did you try it? When writing a UTF8 function, time ago, I had a similar problem which I solved it by using unsigned chars.

Comment: Sorry, missed the return type change. This will make it different in some cases. But should not lead to the results the OP is presenting though.

Comment: @EnricoMigliore by doing this, It works perfectly :). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Using PORTC to check the functionality of your function is going to cause multiple issues.

For example it is a 7 bit register with bit 3 missing. Then RC4 and RC5 are not under complete control of the PORTC alone, the USB peripheral has control over it. And they can only be used as input, so the state depends on the USB or the voltage at the pin, but never on what you write to the PORTC register.

So that means, that bits 3, 4 and 5 are all not what you write to them (likely 0).

So for your 100 the result would likely be (100 & 0xC7) which happens to be 68.

This problem does not explain however why your `get_MSB` returns an unexpected 0 instead of a 1.

Make your life easier by not using peripheral registers to check that a function returns the right value. If your debugger is horrible and does not allow to step into a simple

```
if (100 == get_LSB(100))
{
   volatile unsigned char dummy = 0U;
}
```

You could instead toggle a pin (which you know you can measure and works correctly).